# Maintaining visibility of rightbarButton?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

Hello friends I have added a `UIImageView` and `UIBarButtonItem` on `Navigationbar` in `rootViewController`. on clicking `BarButten` it pushes a second viewController. up to this every thing works fine but when i pop secondary viewController  `UIBarButton` in `rootViewController` gets invisible. can any one tell me how to solve this problem.

```
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, nav.navigationBar.frame.size.width, nav.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    UIImage *navImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar-iPad.png"];
    imageView.image = navImage;
}
else
{
    UIImage *navImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar-iPhone.png"];
    imageView.image = navImage;
}

[nav.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

[nav pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: No. No one but you can solve this. However, if you post the relevant code snippets, then perhaps someone here can help you.

Comment: put your code in viewWillAppear in rootViewController

Comment: viewWillAppear doesn't helped.@hiren443

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add a custom background to UInavigationBar. [Try This Link to add Custom Background Image in iOS 5](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/ios-5-customize-uinavigationbar-and-uibarbuttonitem-with-appearance-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it disappears is that every UIViewController has it's own set of buttons/titles to display on the Navigation Bar. So when you push a new view, it automatically hides the buttons/title of the one below.

If you want buttons that look the same, you have to recreate them in the new UIViewController.

If you need EXACTLY those buttons, instead of pushing a new view controller like you are now,
you can do this:

```
UINavigationController * navcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewcontroller];
[navcontrol setNavigationBarHidden: YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: navcontrol animated:YES];
[navcontrol release];
[viewcontroller release];
```

Comment: i think there is a confusion. i don't want that button in new viewController. i want that when i return back to rootViewController from second ViewController the BarButton should be visible as it was before pushing second ViewController. thanks for response.